# Get list values in tag 'a' one by one using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am going to make a tag cloud manually.Everything is going well but I face a little problem. Below is my code :

HTML:

```
    <ul id="tagCloud">
            <li id="tagcloud_li">Item1</li>
                <li id="tagcloud_li">Item2</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="vis">
            <div class="set_texts">

            </div>
     </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
         $(function() {
                var liArray = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
                var list_item = [];
                for(var i=0; i < liArray.length ;i++){
                    list_item.push($(liArray[i]).text());
                    var get_item_value = ($(liArray[i]).text());

                    var create_text = $('#vis').find('.set_texts').append($('<a href="" id="tagcloud_list" class="tagcloud_li'+i+'">'));
                    $('#vis').find(".tagcloud_li"+i).text($(liArray[i]).text());
                }
                var count_li = $('#vis').find('#tagcloud_list').length+1;
                for(var i=0; i < liArray.length ;i++){

                        for(var j = 0; j < count_li; j++){

                                   if(i == j){
                                       var get_item_value = ($(liArray[i]).text());
                                       var get_class = $('#vis').find('a').text(get_item_value).append(get_class);
                                    }
                                }
                }
             });
```

Output of this code is :

```
      <a href="" id="tagcloud_list" class="tagcloud_li0" style="font-size:12px;text-decoration:none; color: #FF7600;">Item2</a>
      <a href="" id="tagcloud_list" class="tagcloud_li0" style="font-size:12px;text-decoration:none; color: #FF7600;">Item2</a>
```

In this output both  contain value 'Item2'.

But I want to get value 'item1' in first tag 'a' and value 'item2' in second tag 'a' .Like :

```
      <a href="" id="tagcloud_list" class="tagcloud_li0" style="font-size:12px;text-decoration:none; color: #FF7600;">Item1</a>
      <a href="" id="tagcloud_list" class="tagcloud_li0" style="font-size:12px;text-decoration:none; color: #FF7600;">Item2</a>
```

How I can get this?

Comment: it is always good to make a fiddle of your code and paste link in your question...

Comment: Actually I don't know how to code in fiddle. in fiddle how to connect JavaScript src?

Comment: This code looks extraordinarily complex ... maybe try reducing code first. I guess your intention takes a few lines in jQuery code, only.

Comment: @cepharum Not like that bro. Actually I am new in JavaScript. Thats why I do it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul id="tagCloud">
    <li id="tagcloud_li">Item1</li>
    <li id="tagcloud_li">Item2</li>
</ul>
<div id="vis">
    <div class="set_texts"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.set_text {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Arial;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    text-align:left;
}
.tagcloud {
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FF7600;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var container = $("#vis").find(".set_texts");
    $("#tagCloud").find('li').each(function (i) {
        $('<a href="" id="tagcloud_list" class="tagcloud tagcloud_li' + i + '"/>').text($(this).text()).appendTo(container);
    });
});
```

[Sample: (Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodvcs/hNrMJ/2/)

Created tag cloud is simple but it's what your code does.

Comment: Thanks bro.Its working. Many many thanks for reducing this code. I learn many things from your code. Actually I am new in JS thats whay my code was so complex. Thanks again bro :) @Mahmoodvcs

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs try caching target of `appendTo()` as its queried on every iteration of `.each()`. Is using `$(a).find(b)` faster than using single `$("a b")`?

Comment: I have read somewhere that `$(a).find(b)` is faster than `$("a b")`. That makes sense to me.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs that's okay and makes sense to me too, but caching `$("#vis").find(".set_texts")` would improve your code further, e.g. declaring `var cached;` in scope of outer function and use ...`appendTo(cached = cached || $("#vis").find(".set_texts"))` at end of third line then.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very complex and thus you won't see the point for sure. I.e.,

```
var liArray = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var list_item = [];
for(var i=0; i < liArray.length ;i++){
    list_item.push($(liArray[i]).text());
    var get_item_value = ($(liArray[i]).text());

    var create_text = $('#vis').find('.set_texts').append($('<a href="" id="tagcloud_list" class="tagcloud_li'+i+'" style="font-size:12px;text-decoration:none; color: #FF7600;">'));
    $('#vis').find(".tagcloud_li"+i).text($(liArray[i]).text());
}
```

might be reduced to this:

```
$("li").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var text = item.text();

    $('<a href="" class="tagcloud_list" id="tagcloud_li'+i+'" style="font-size:12px;text-decoration:none; color: #FF7600;">')
        .text( text )
        .appendTo( $('#vis').find('.set_texts') );
});
```

Your example of this loop is fetching same information from DOM several times and drops it in one of those cases. That's expensive by means of performance. Next you might reverse way of adding the `<a>` so you won't need to add it to the target container first just to get query that one to give it back afterwards.

The resulting `<a>` are all using same ID which is bad, too. So try swapping class and ID.

According to your issue this code seems to be crucial:

```
var get_class = $('#vis').find('a').text(get_item_value).append(get_class);
```

It is finding *all `<a>`* in your target assigning single text to *all of them*.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript to this.. And I used Jquery..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var liArray = $("li");
  var i;
  for(i=0;i < liArray.length;i++){
    $("div.set_texts").append('<a href="" id="tagcloud_list" class="tagcloud_li'+i+'" style="font-size:12px;text-decoration:none; color: #FF7600;">' + liArray[i].innerHTML + '</a>'); 
  }
  });
```

Comment: This ain't improving existing answers and it's badly integrating jQuery in that it's iterating the resulting array of elements itself and in that it's mixing native DOM API and use of jQuery ... see `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Sorry.. But I am 15 year old boy.. And I am also studying Jquery

Comment: It's nothing bad about learning something, but try focusing on reading answers rather than posting clones of existing ones then.